# pandas dataframe correctly displays the column names but still throws KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

Following code correctly displays all 150 columns of a `UTF-16 LE BOM` data file, but when referencing a column in the code below, it still throws a well know [KeyError](https://dataindependent.com/pandas/keyerror-pandas-how-to-fix/) that indicates that it does not recognize the columns. The same error occurs on any of 150 columns. **Question**: Why it may be happening and how can we fix the issue?

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/MyDataFile.txt', sep='~', low_memory=False, quotechar='"', header='infer', encoding='UTF-16LE')

print(list(df.columns)) #correctly displays a list of all 150 columns
print(df['OrderID']) #throws KeyError: 'OrderID'
```

**Sample data file**:

```
FirstName~LastName~OrderID~City~.....
Kim~Doe~1234~New York~...............
Bob~Mason~456~Seattle~...............
..................
```

Comment: Umm.  Can you double check that you have the square brackets in your code for the line of code throwing the error.  When I copied your sample above, everything worked.  However, when I typed in the line of code like this: print(df('Order ID')), then I got the error, "print(df('OrderID')) #throws KeyError: 'OrderID'".

Comment: @NoDakker I double checked, and is correctly typed as: `print(df['OrderID'])`. This exact syntax works fine for data files that are `UTF-8`.